# I created one landing page, when customers fill all the details it should display in the custom module grid in magento admin panel

Tags: database, grid, frontend, forms

I created one landing page, when customers fill all the details it should display in the custom module grid in magento admin panel,

how can i implement, 
`<form action="">`, what to put in action part.

Comment: You need to create controller to post the form data and you need to create a model to access the database table. After that you have to create ui_component for that table. refer - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Answer (score 1):

**feedback_customer_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   layout="2columns-right" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
   "../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/
   Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" src_type="url" />
</head>
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::feedback_form.phtml" ifconfig="FeedBack/FeedBackgroup/show_feedback_module"/>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

**feedback_form.phtml**

```
<h1>FeedBack Form</h1>
<form class="form" id="feedback-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl()?>feedback/index/save" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" data-validate='{"required": true}'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" data-validate='{"required": true}'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" data-validate='{"required": true, "validate-email":true}'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" name="message" data-validate='{"required": true}'></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeMp8sUAAAAALt7DEdC5RSX9UMUvIpOQMeCOwhb"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" name="feedback_submit" id="feedback_submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```